# How to access websocket from remote machine

Tags: java, html, websocket, glassfish

I have created a websocket server in java and glassfish server is hosting it at port 8080. The address of the websocket server is **ip:8080/EchoChamber/echo**
 I created this websocket server using the following [link](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/12/websockets-an-introduction/)
My clients are some embedded microcontrollers and my web based application where I view the results (in chrome IE explorer).
My client app is using some java script to establish the connection to websocket server:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var webSocket = 
new WebSocket("ws://ip:8080/EchoChamber/echo");

webSocket.onerror = function(event) {
  onError(event)
};

webSocket.onopen = function(event) {
  onOpen(event)
};

webSocket.onmessage = function(event) {
  onMessage(event)
};

function onMessage(event) {
//display message in textboxes
}
```

The issue is I can view results on my app when I am at local host, but when I am at remote desktop the web browser gives the error that page at remote ip is undefined. Can any one tell me how can I connect my remote host browser to websocket server. I tried to access port ip:8080 from my remote machine and I can access it which means glass fish server has no restrictions. It is websocket  which is putting some restrictions. Can any one help me out.

Answer (score 1):

It's a javascript code not java. I believe javascript has a restriction for cross site scripting. That's why it works at localhost and doesn't work for other hosts. I think you can disable the safety setting in the browser and it might work but it's usually forbidden.

Comment: i said client is on java script where websocket server is written in java

Comment: Well that's the problem. If the website is opened in your computer but it tries to open a websocke to to another IP it will fail.  The website should be hosted on some server and the websocket must be on the same server.

Comment: actually the websocket is at glassflish server and the website is on apache server. :(

Answer (score 0):

Html page containing the javascript should get rendered from the same domain otherwise browser security will not allow you to connect to different host (host which did not serve the content or possibly from different domain)